# How long is JWT time to live without "exp" field?

Tags: jwt

How long is JWT time to live without "exp" field? For example, this token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
    {
      "alg": "HS256",
      "typ": "JWT"
    }
    {
      "sub": "1234567890",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "iat": 1516239022
    }
```

does not have "exp". How long before it's updated, or will this token not be updated in my application?

Comment: If my or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.If there's still anything unclear in my answer, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

When there's is no expiration time defined, the token won't expire. Then it would be valid until you change the secret that was used for signing and validation.

Of course you can also implement a mechanism based on the issued at (iat) claim and not accepting a token of a certain age, but this depends on your own implementation.